# Javascript hide/show questions depending on user input values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to hide and/or show form elements when a user selects certain values. 
For example, if the user selects "yes" to the consent question, I need it to show a few questions, However, if they change their response to the consent question, I need it to hide those questions.

Here is what I have come up with so far...

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var input = document.getElementById('consent');
    var consent_responses = [{ "0": hideConsent },{ "1": showConsent }];
    input.addEventListner('click', function () {
        var consent_response;
        if (consent_responses[this.value]) {
            content_response = consent_responses[this.Function()]
        }
        else {
            content_response = consent_responses[this.Function]
        }
    });

    function showConsent(){
        $("#date").show(),
        $("#referrer").show(),
        $("#f_name").show(),
        $("#phone_num").show(),
        $("#leave_msg").show(),
        $("#email").show(),
    };
    function hideConsent(){
        $("#date").hide(),
        $("#referrer").hide(),
        $("#f_name").hide(),
        $("#phone_num").hide(),
        $("#leave_msg").hide(),
        $("#email").hide(),
    }; });
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7jX47/1/

Comment: Maybe add the html and make a fiddle? It would help if you want a quick answer...

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle complete with the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jX47/2/)

Basically I only fixed a few typos (did you actually try your code before you posted here?) and added event listeners to the radio buttons with

```
document.getElementById(...).addEventListener(...)
```

I also gave your radio buttons unique IDs.

Comment: I do like this method... But I have a dumb question, when saving the values entered to the database, php takes the name not the id correct?

Comment: After submitting the form your server will be processing the data using the names of the `<input>`-tags, yes. To be able to address elements properly (client-side) you should always use unique IDs in HTML, though.

Comment: Thank you, I just needed to hear that from someone else to verify. I like your solution.

Comment: To take this to the next step. If the user clicks on no I do not consent after they filled out say 2 questions, How would I reset all values when the user clicks on "no I do not consent"?

Comment: You could add something like `document.getElementById('date').value='';` (for the text input elements). You will have to make sure you have unique IDs there. Right now several elements in your code are called "date".

Comment: If you are looking to get dropdown values would you do something like

document.getElementById('referrer_').valueOf('5').addEventListener('click', function ()
?

Comment: Probably best to look at how to manipulate input elements with JS. If you can't find anything (You should, there are lots of resources on that sort of thing), post it as a separate question as it's rather outside the scope of this one and it might make it easier for other people with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

This can be simplified:

```
var input = document.getElementById('consent');
// Let's use the value as key, and the functions as values
var consent_responses = {
    "0" : hideConsent,
    "1" : showConsent
};
input.addEventListener("click", function () {
    // Get the appropriate function given the value, and invoke it
    consent_responses[this.value]();
});

function hideConsent() {
    // ...
}

function showConsent() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Have made the changes, Better looking, functions identical to problem

Answer (score 1):

It's better to envelop your questions (that needs to be hidden) by a **div** with a class **".hidden"** or style **"display: none;"**. And simplify your code by simply asking that **div** to **show() or hide()** when needed.

Like so:

```
<form id="screening">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 nopad" id="create">
    <div class="form-group text-center">
        <b>Do you agree to answer the screening questions?</b><br />
        <div class="radio" id="consent">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="consent" id="consent" value="1">
                Yes, I consent
            </label>
        </div><br />
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="consent" id="consent" value="0">
                No, I do not consent
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- simplify by using this -->
<div id="questions" style="display: none;">

    <div class="form-group" id="date">
        <label for="date">What is today's date?</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="referrer">
        <label for="referrer">How did you hear about us/our studies?</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="referrer" id="referrer">
            <option></option>
            <option value="1">Flyers</option>
            <option value="2">Print Media</option>
            <option value="3">A friend</option>
            <option value="4">Online (e.g., Craigslist)</option>
            <option value="5">Other</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="other_explain">
        <label for="other_explain">Please specify other source.</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="other_explain" name="other_explain"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="f_name">
        <label for="f_name">What is your first name?</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="f_name" name="f_name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="phone_num">
        <label for="phone_num">What is a phone number at which you can be contacted?   </label>
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone_num" name="phone_num" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="leave_msg">
        <label for="leave_msg">If we call and you are not available, may we leave a message?</label><br />
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="leave_msg" id="leave_msg" value="1">
                Yes
            </label>
        </div><br />
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="leave_msg" id="leave_msg" value="0">
                No
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="email">
        <label for="email">What is an e-mail at which you can be contacted?</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" />
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

and in your javascript instead of using this:

```
function showConsent(){
        $("#date").show(),
        $("#referrer").show(),
        $("#f_name").show(),
        $("#phone_num").show(),
        $("#leave_msg").show(),
        $("#email").show(),
    };
```

you use:

```
function showConsent(){
        $("#questions").show(),
    };
```

Comment: This is only part of the code. But yes I will be adding display:none to each question by default. And depending on the input, I will continue to hide, or show each question. I cannot group all questions, instead each question has to be hidden individually (due to logic later in the code) But thank you. –